# Abstract class cast operator

Tags: c#, casting, abstract-class, operator-keyword

Poco items are wrapped.

```
abstract class AbstractPocoUI<T> {
    protected T PocoItem;
}

class PocoA {

}
class PocoAUI:AbstractPocoUI<PocoA> {

}
```

I want to do something like this

```
var c = new ObservableCollection<PocoAUI>(collectionOfTypePocoA.Cast<PocoAUI>());
```

How can i override cast operator in abstract class?
What should i do in `AbstractPocoUI` to get for example `PocoAUI` with `PocoA` in `PocoItem` field ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can implement `IConvertible` interface or create a `TypeConverter` but casting cannot be overriden.

---

Have a look at Implicit Operator overloading [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z5z9kes2%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: What about overriding implicit operator?

Comment: How can i create AbstractPocoUI version of PocoA object inside overriding of implicit operator?